# basic application setText() not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.v_krkoru.androidapp.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/message_text"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

```
package com.example.v_krkoru.androidapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.androidapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {
        Intent intent  = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

package com.example.v_krkoru.androidapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);

}
```

here i entered two java codes of activities which are interlinked by means of intent what iam trying to do is when i type a message and click on send button The next activity should display the message typed on new screen
Iam learning this from android website and struck here as setText() method is not working.just now added xml code for reference to those who are willing to answer

Comment: Where are you calling the `public void sendMessage(View view)` method?

Comment: it triggers when i click the send button

Comment: Like do have an OnClickListener interface or are you calling `onClick` from the layout file

Comment: use getIntent() inside onCreate() method

Comment: Show XML code for the TextView you are trying to show

Comment: your getIntent() not getting called

Comment: just now added xml code in the question please check from the question

Comment: thanks @GeetaGupta this solved my issue

Comment: Show DisplayMessageActivity XML code

Answer (score 2):

// you have written findViewById() outside onCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); // this line should be inside your onCreate method.
}
```

Comment: the problem is with getIntent() method is not inside onCreate()

Comment: But  this should be inside your oncreate method u have written outside" TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);"

Answer (score 2):

This code is working fine on my side.

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acivity_demo);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

       mTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mTextview.setText(message);

    }
}
```